# How to write the trigger for the following promt in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, database-trigger

Create a trigger “insert_inventory” on table “Inventory”. The trigger is fired after a row is inserted in table “Inventory”. After a row is inserted in table “inventory”, the “itemid”, the insertion time, and the action is inserted in table “Inventory_history”. The action is set to ‘add an item’. The oldprice is set to null.

Comment: What have you tried already, and what problems have you had?  What do the table CREATE statements look like?

Comment: Read up on triggers here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html , write some code , post code here together with any problems you encounter.